# What's the difference between git checkout <remote>/<branch> vs git checkout <branch>?

Tags: git, github

What's the difference between `git checkout <remote>/<branch>` vs `git checkout <branch>`? When do you need to use `git checkout <remote>/<branch>`?

Comment: Related to / possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670173/why-does-git-tell-me-not-currently-on-any-branch-after-i-run-git-checkout-ori

Comment: `git checkout <remote>/<branch>` is almost never what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout <remote>/<branch>` will check out the commit that `git rev-parse refs/remotes/<remote>/<branch>` resolves to, and leave you in "detached HEAD" state.

`git checkout <branch>` will check out the local branch given, or, depending on your configuration, might automatically create a local branch named `<branch>` that is set up to track `<remote>/<branch>` for you, and then check out that local branch. It will not leave you in a "detached HEAD" state, but on a local branch (unless it fails for some reason, like you have it configured not to create branches automatically, and the named branch doesn't exist).

Answer (score 3):

The key thing to understand is that *remote branches are normal branches* with the name `<remote>/<branch>`.  They are just references (labels) pointing at a commit.  The main difference is you can't commit to them.

Why would you check out a remote branch?  To inspect the state of the project upstream, maybe to try building it.  Otherwise, you wouldn't.

There are uses for referencing a remote branch...

- `git diff remote/branch` to look at the differences between your branch and the remote.
- `git log remote/branch..HEAD` to look at changes with the remote.
- `git branch -f branch remote/branch` to throw out all your local changes.