# HEAD detached at the HEAD commit id, what's the meaning?

Tags: git, git-detached-head

`git status` says:

```
HEAD detached at e1997bd
```

and `git rev-parse HEAD` says:

```
e1997bd
```

What's the meaning of this?

I was thinking HEAD detached means HEAD is not pointing to to branch tip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670173/why-does-git-tell-me-not-currently-on-any-branch-after-i-run-git-checkout-ori/25670296#25670296

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Read through: 
http://gitolite.com/detached-head.html

You can also look at:
http://gitolite.com/gcs.html#(48)

The head points to the commit, that's not the problem. The problem is that it's no longer a reference to a local branch name. It's the actual SHA1 hash of the commit.

This may have happened if you did:

```
git checkout <commit_id>
  -- or --
git checkout origin/master
```

To fix this, do

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

Comment: Can also happen if you checkout a remote tracking branch e.g. origin/master

Comment: I did `git checkout <commit_id>` but it doesn't recognize any remote branches. Trying to checkout another branch gives the same error as trying to get a new commit. `pathspec <branch name or commit_id> did not match any file(s) known to git`