# Repo not pointing to HEAD branch

Tags: git, unix, git-branch

I did a checkout on the repo for my production site because I wanted to check a change. Now I pointed back my repo to the latest commit but now is not pointing to HEAD branch so instead of this

```
[gcardonav@gambit workshop]$ git status
# On branch master
```

I am getting this

```
[root@prod website]# git status
# Not currently on any branch.
```

I tried `git reset --hard origin/HEAD` but is still not pointing to branch master. What do I need to do?

Comment: Thank you @zaratustra, that was what I could not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HEAD` pointer is detached, e.g. `HEAD` points at a commit that is not pointed by any of your branches. To get back to `master` you can run:

`git checkout master`

Now `HEAD` points at the commit that is pointed by `master`. Read [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) for more information

Comment: *You have `HEAD` is detached, e.g. `HEAD` points at a commit that is not pointed by any of your branches.* That's a bit imprecise. You're in detached-HEAD state when `HEAD` points at some commit *directly*, whether the latter is a branch's tip or not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670173/why-does-git-tell-me-not-currently-on-any-branch-after-i-run-git-checkout-ori/25670296#25670296

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to express it more precisely.

Comment: Amend your answer accordingly and you'll get my upvote.