# How to fix Github release deployment of Latex project?

Tags: git, github, latex, travis-ci

In Github I've set Travis to automatically compile an article written in Latex language. To do so I followed the recipe available in [this site](https://harshjv.github.io/blog/setup-latex-pdf-build-using-travis-ci/). After I manage to make it work, this is how the [repository](https://github.com/BlockchainLibrary/CollectiveDecentralizedJudgements) became.

It was working well a couple commits before. It now builds successfully but the deployment to Github releases fails with the following error:

```
Deploying application
Already up-to-date!
Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (e44e5f8a271617ad8063767ccb89861985b8a28d)
```

The Raw log can be seen [here](https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/183788727/log.txt?deansi=true).

I already tested the solution from this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735556/git-not-currently-on-any-branch-is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-back-on-a-branch) without success.

---

Later on today I was editing [this](https://github.com/BlockchainLibrary/BlockchainLibraryWhitepaper) other GitHub Latex article and surprisingly the same problem happened (See build log [here](https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/183942816/log.txt?deansi=true)). Commit triggered build succeeds, but tag triggered build fails when deploying. This is a strong indication that something else rather than my code might have changed the deployment behavior.

Comment: Interesting that someone entered here and rated negative this post without even commenting why. This is a real problem I'm facing with clear research proof. In my understanding that is an unnaceptable behavior for a community like this since it doesn't help me or others with the same situation in any away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dominic Jodoin from Travis-CI support anwered me:

> Hey Daniel,
>
> Thanks for reaching out and sorry for the troubles.
>
> As a first step, can you tell us if what you want to upload to GitHub is part of your repository or it's rather artifacts generated by your build process? If it's the latter, can you try adding the following to your `deploy:` section of your .travis.yml file:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  skip_cleanup: true
  ⋮
```

As what I wanted to upload are artifacts generated from my build process, I promptly changed to `skip_cleanup: true`. Once created and pushed a new tag, the deployment succeeded.