# Reconnect git local to GitHub remote without losing a new local branch and commits

Tags: git, github, git-remote

With some help I managed to recover a local git project from a `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` issue... [Why does git not recognise my local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66830941/why-does-git-not-recognise-my-local-repository)

But now my local git is ahead on a new local branch (that doesn't exist on the GitHub remote) and is disconnected from the existing remote origin.

- `git remote -v` returns nothing

How do I reconnect and push the local git to the existing GitHub remote without losing the new local branch with it's commits?

Comment: `is disconnected from the existing remote origin` can you clarify what this means please, e.g. by adding the command and output when you try `git checkout my-branch; git push` to the question?

Comment: Added `git remote -v` thanks @AD7six , I'll try to get into the habit of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the remote:

```
git remote add origin http://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Then push the changes.

Comment: Ok that's simpler than I thought thank you! One question though, does this automatically track all the existing branches or do I need to use `git push -u origin branch` for each branch?

Comment: Figured it out, all the branches need to be reset to track the relevant remote branch by using `git push -u origin branch` for each branch

Comment: @Dan: actually you need only a `git branch --set-upstream-to` for each branch. The `git push` option `-u` means: *after a successful push, run `git branch --set-upstream-to` as well*. Note that each branch has either no upstream, or one upstream, so if some branches already have an upstream set (though none will in this particular case) this could *change* the upstream, if you pick a different one this time. For more about upstreams, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452).